# GWT Requestfactory 3 nested object

Tags: gwt, gxt, requestfactory

I have a GWT application with **Requestfactory**. On the serverside I have a service returning a triple nested object. A contains a `List<B> #B`. Each B contains a C.
When I fire my request to `findAll(A).with("B","C").fire(receiver)` it only returns B values. C is null. In debugging I see that up to the DAO the A object is properly set with all values.
(Clientside all extend EntityProxy)

Right now I need to fire seperate requests to get C for every B selected in the list of A. Which means more back and forth...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If A contains B, you need `.with("B")`. If A contains C, you would add `"C"` to that call, but since *B* contains C, you instead add `"B.C"`:

```
findAll(A).with("B","B.C").fire(receiver)
```

Real world example: Person (A) has Address (C), and Person has Employer (B), and Employer also has Address (C). You were asking RequestFactory to send Person, their Employer and the Person's address, but *not* the Employer's Address.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: It's that situation that I have. So a company (A) has an employee (B) that lives in country (C) (C has several getters (get Name() I need)). When I already created my company I want to add an employee. Fill in it's information and use a preloaded combobox for the country (ListStore<C>()). When I save the company, I add .with("employee", "employee.country").(receiver), the returnValue contains everything of company and employee, but employee.getCountry().getName() throw nullpointer on "getCountry().getName()". When I debug the proxy is populated in the fire().

Comment: If you correctly are requesting B and B.C, but a.getB().getC() is null (so a.getB().getC().getName() has an error), then something else is wrong, probably in your Locators (or static methods that fulfill that purpose). Your question specifically asked about with("B", "C") which is wrong - if with("B", "B.C") also doesn't work, you should update your question, and include code this time.